# How to get members perperties Get-ADUser Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm using the ._MemberOf GetADUser to try and retrieve the members for the users.
I can't post the data I receive as its confidential, but what I want to retrieve is:

```
CN=Name-of-user, OU=Team, OU=Group (eg Admin accounts), DC=domain
```

But what I actually get contains the CN, OU & DC parameters but not for the name and group, but for a vast number of other things. Its 2838 characters long, it seems to be the permissions for different applications or something? Is the MemberOf parameter wrong? There's no Member parameter for get ADUser.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - the information I wanted was ._DistinguishedName, I already had a DistinguishedName column however that was for the group, not the user.